# How do I create a reference to an object before the object's element in FXML?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have two objects defined in an FXML document. I want one of them to have a reference, also defined in FXML, to the other. The FXML element of the object that has the other object comes first in the document. When loaded via javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader, the property is left unassigned. It *does* assign the property if the object that has the other object comes second. Is there a way to assign an object reference to the property of an object that comes earlier in the FXML document?

Here's a minimal complete verifiable example. The object that has a reference to another and comes before it doesn't get its property assigned and when tested it's null. The one that comes after the object it references does get its property assigned and prints out the toString() of the object.

issue.fxml:

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import test.control.*?>

<HBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" id="pane1" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <FriendlyButton fx:id="priorObjectReference" friend="$normalButton" />
    <Button fx:id="normalButton" />
    <FriendlyButton fx:id="subsequentObjectReference" friend="$normalButton" />
</HBox>
```

FXMLIssue.java, loads above FXML and tries to print the object references:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import test.control.FriendlyButton;

public class FXMLIssue extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Parent container = null;
        try {
            container = FXMLLoader.load(Paths.get("issue.fxml").toUri().toURL());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLIssue.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to load file.", ex);
            Platform.exit();
        }

        FriendlyButton priorObjectReference = (FriendlyButton) container.lookup("#priorObjectReference");
        System.out.println(priorObjectReference.getFriend() == null ? "priorObjectReference's friend property wasn't loaded from FXML" : "priorObjectReference's friend is: " + priorObjectReference.getFriend().toString());

        FriendlyButton subsequentObjectReference = (FriendlyButton) container.lookup("#subsequentObjectReference");
        System.out.println(subsequentObjectReference.getFriend() == null ? "subsequentObjectReference's friend property wasn't loaded from FXML" : "subsequentObjectReference's friend is: " + subsequentObjectReference.getFriend().toString());

        Platform.exit();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

FriendlyButton.java, just a class that has a property that refers to another object in FXML:

```
package test.control;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class FriendlyButton extends Button {
    private Button mFriend;

    public Button getFriend() {
        return mFriend;
    }

    public void setFriend(Button friend) {
        mFriend = friend;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<HBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" id="pane1" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <fx:define>
        <Button fx:id="normalButton" />
    </fx:define>
    <FriendlyButton fx:id="priorObjectReference" friend="$normalButton" />
    <fx:reference source="normalButton" />
    <FriendlyButton fx:id="subsequentObjectReference" friend="$normalButton" />
</HBox>
```

Comment: This is a good solution. It wouldn't hurt the quality of the answer though, if you'd add 1 or 2 sentences that explain, how this works... +1 nonetheless

Comment: @fabian Unfortunately my level of language proficiency is very small.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to rewrite `FriendlyButton` class with a JavaFX property and use an [expression binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding) (`${}`) for the first reference at least:

```
<FriendlyButton fx:id="priorObjectReference" friend="${normalButton}" />
<Button fx:id="normalButton"/>
<FriendlyButton fx:id="subsequentObjectReference" friend="$normalButton" />
```

// `FriendlyButton.java:`

```
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class FriendlyButton extends Button {
    private ObjectProperty<Button> friend = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    public final Button getFriend() { return friend.get(); }
    public final void setFriend(Button value) { friend.set(value); }
    public final ObjectProperty<Button> friendProperty() { return friend; }
}
```